# Saving information from facebook open id

Tags: php, facebook, openid

I am doing a project in which user cal log in by registering to the site as well as using facebook login information . 
I am able to log in using facebbook login information but how will I save the information of the user so that next time he logs in
the site will show his information (like in stackoverflow) . I am using PHP - smarty .

`print_r($_SESSION)` is

```
     Array
(
    [fb_117743971608120_state] => 9cec0afaeea766a4c604308d750cae27
    [fb_183884308338472_code] => 085FCZlNVcOmjOb5-oejUDGSXEypJf6K5gOGCUjbFDg.eyJpdiI6Ii1nODJpOWFuZHh0bUh4VzNVc3d3OEEifQ.1DvUVqsbPFAhK9lgOYvwBH9qrpQkjYhbA9s8nVxCgnefVyGQX3KjSSCEiN1Rs0GfnGqgwYESDuPlDjEpPRGhkK5kn4U4CExgm22URCr45EM44vjL5wEFyT8WbWzPoE0_tYSkHgmEc5TPNBP1GB1z-g
    [fb_183884308338472_access_token] => 183884308338472|2.AQB3ExZ8y5FeCiR5.3600.1310461200.1-100000525094244|JxU5yIl32MnS2jWuci_p6qllPEI
    [fb_183884308338472_user_id] => 100000525094244
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with Facebook logins, but I am going to presume that it operates in a similar fashion to any other login. That is, you'll need to utilize some sort of persistent structure that can be utilized on a visitors return.

For instance:

```
<?php
    // Start the session (important!)
    session_start();

    // Set the session on login
    $_SESSION['login_token'] = "some_identification_info";

    // You can check to see if the login was successful, if it is
    // then the user is logged in. This will persist across pages, and
    // you can set the "time" to expire.
?>
```

You may also take a look at cookies. Please note that the above code was not tested, I just typed it out and its 2AM so there is a very real chance I missed something. Take a look at the documentation for [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) and [Cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php).