# Unable to save user information after authenticating with facebook openid

Tags: php, facebook, openid

I have successfully logged in using facebook openid. Now I need to store his information so that next time he logs in site remembers him . So how will I approach ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving information from facebook open id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660657/saving-information-from-facebook-open-id)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a rare question ...

[Saving information from facebook open id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660657/saving-information-from-facebook-open-id)

Was asked not too long ago.  I'd highly suggest searching stackoverflow.com for the answers before posting...

[If OpenID, what user data do I still need to save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164847/if-openid-what-user-data-do-i-still-need-to-save)

Comment: But I did not find my answer there

Comment: *The provider will give you a unique ID for each user - this you need to save. It's how you will match up the user that just logged in with a record in your database.*  Store it in a flat text file.  Store it in MySQL ... store it whever you feel most comfortable...?